# Spelling differences in Bulgaria Pazardzhik province ADM1

Tags: google-maps, google-geocoding-api

Depending on the input to Google geocoding, we are seeing different spellings for the ADM1 province Pazardzhik.

Input "4400 Pazardzhik Center, Pazardzhik, Bulgaria" and the ADM1 entry in the geocoding result will be "Pazardjik".

Input "Pazardzhik, Bulgaria" and the ADM1 entry in the geocoding result will be "Pazardzik".

The nomenclature is supposed to be following ISO 3166-2; which gives the spelling "Pazardzhik" for the ADM1 of this region.  I haven't seen that spelling come back from searches around this area.  Although officially there are no official names for Bulgarian ADM1 regions, can we get a single spelling chosen and standardized, or maybe use the one from ISO 3166-2?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code or requests that produce the Pazardjik and Pazardzhik output?

Comment: I bieleve you got an answer from Google in the public issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/109833938